# How to set Font Size based on the Scree Size of a Android Device?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using `Jetpack Compose` I want to display the Local Time in **Full Screen** in **Landscape Orientation** on an Android Device similar to this image:

[image]

As shown in the image, the text `12:20` has close to maximum font size it can have in the screen. The font size of `PM` also depends on the screen size.

So, how do I achieve this functionality? I would like it the composable to work on all types of screens. (Different types of screens for Phones and Tablets)

It would be helpful if you could just help me in fitting the local time on a screen with the maximum possible font size.

Comment: Could [this](https://proandroiddev.com/preventing-font-scaling-in-jetpack-compose-8a2cd0f09d23) help?

Comment: Preventing the font from scaling using `sp` is the secondary objective, for which this article is definitely helpful. But the primary objective is to identify the maximum font size based on the screen size that I should set in order to display the text without any overflowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of accomplishing this would be measuring texts width against a BoxWithConstraints in a loop and increasing font size while text width is smaller than container width.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun DynamicTextSizeSample() {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Color.Red).alignByBaseline()
        ) {

            val text = "12:20"
            val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

            val fontSize by remember {
                derivedStateOf {

                    var textSize = 0.sp
                    var textWidth = 0

                    while (textWidth < constraints.maxWidth) {

                        val result = textMeasurer.measure(
                            text = text,
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = (textSize.value + .5).sp,
                                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                                    includeFontPadding = false
                                )
                            )
                        )

                        textWidth = result.size.width

                        if (textWidth <= constraints.maxWidth) {
                            textSize = result.layoutInput.style.fontSize
                        }

                        println("textWidth: $textWidth, textSize: $textSize")
                    }

                    textSize
                }
            }

            Text(text,
                fontSize = fontSize,
                modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Green),
            )
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text("PM", fontSize = 60.sp, modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out different approaches, I finally found this simple and easy to implement solution. In this composable, the `fontSize` is increased by the factor of `resizeFactor` until, the text overflows either horizontally or vertically. After that, it is once reduced for once by the same factor to avoid  the final overflow.

```
@Composable
fun AutoResizableText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val resizeFactor = 1.05f
    var resizedFontStyle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextStyle(
                fontSize = 1.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily(
                    Font(
                        R.font.varelaround_regular
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    }
    var shouldDrawText by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var trueTextSizeNotFound by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    Text(
        text = text,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .drawWithContent {
                if (shouldDrawText) {
                    drawContent()
                }
            },
        softWrap = false,
        style = resizedFontStyle,
        onTextLayout = { result ->
            if(trueTextSizeNotFound){
                if(!result.didOverflowWidth && !result.didOverflowHeight) {
                    resizedFontStyle = resizedFontStyle.copy(
                        fontSize = resizedFontStyle.fontSize * resizeFactor
                    )
                } else {
                    trueTextSizeNotFound = false
                    shouldDrawText = true
                    resizedFontStyle = resizedFontStyle.copy(
                        fontSize = resizedFontStyle.fontSize / resizeFactor
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Since the primary goal was to have the maximum font size without any text overflow, it can be achieved by choosing the `resizeFactor` closer to but greater than `1`. This desired result comes at a cost of huge delay in rendering. I tried to render a single `AutomResizableText()` composable on a phone screen and it took almost 3 seconds to display the text. So, I believe it would be better to save the font size in a datastore after first render and use the same value instead of trying to find the perfect size every time. (Note: This applies to the usecase as mentioned in the question where the dimensions of the parent container remains constant in every render. Otherwise the approach might fail in scenario of split screen or foldable display.)

---

*Point to note that you might not see the desired result while previewing the composable using`@Preview`*

For instance: This is my preview function

```
@Preview(
    device = "spec:parent=pixel_5,orientation=landscape",
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES or Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL
)
@Composable
private fun PreviewAutoResizableText() {
    ScTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            AutoResizableText(text = "12:23" )
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the preview I got: (Complete blank screen)
[image]

But this is screenshot of preview on emulator
[image]

---

Credits:The solution is inspired from the youtube video [How to Create a Magic Text That Always Fits Its Container - Jetpack Compose Tutorial](https://youtu.be/ntlyrFw0F9U)

Comment: Even if you check `!result.didOverflowWidth && !result.didOverflowHeight`doing it with TextMeasurer inside derivedState only triggers one recomposition on calculation